# Giving fairness in execution for threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Consider a situation where thread A has List of strings {string1,string2} and thread B has {string3, string4}. Both threads are trying to execute a block of code, lets say

```
  public void critcalCodeMethod(){
    ....
    ....
    }
```

When thread A and B are in action, suppose thread C which has {string1,string5} and thread D which has {string3, string 6} are trying to access the same `critcalCodeMethod()` code, they should be put in a fairness queue and should be allowed to execute in the order in which they arrived. In other words, thread A and B can execute in parallel since they dont have common strings. Thread C should be executed first right after thread A finishes. Similarly thread D should be executed first right after thread B. If any other threads say thread E with value {string1, string7} should be allowed after thread C. Please suggest a locking mechanism to achieve this in java

Answer (score 0):

[ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) has an optional fairness parameter that can probably be used to implement your logic.

However, depending on what those Strings are, where they come from and how you're using them there may be more suitable ways to handle concurrency (`Guava`'s [Striped](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) comes to mind).